# Php attachment not sending throught php mailer

Tags: php

I'm trying to allow my form to attach files and is not working.

500 Internal Server Error for now:

my code is:

HTML

```
<form action="email2.php" method="post" class="form" id="form1" name="contact-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="userfile" id="file-1" class="inputfile inputfile-1" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple />
</form>
```

PHP email2.php

```
<?php
/**
* PHPMailer simple file upload and send example
*/
$msg = '';
if (array_key_exists('userfile', $_FILES)) {
// First handle the upload
// Don't trust provided filename - same goes for MIME types
// See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#114004 for more thorough upload validation
$uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['userfile']['name']));
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    // Upload handled successfully
    // Now create a message
    // This should be somewhere in your include_path
    require 'PhpMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail->setFrom('CV');
    $mail->addAddress('kubographics@gmail.com', 'Eugenio Keller');
    $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer file sender';
    $mail->msgHTML("My message body");
    // Attach the uploaded file
    $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'My uploaded file');
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        $msg = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        $msg = "Message sent!";
    }
} else {
    $msg = 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
    }
 }
?>
```

PhpMailerAutoload.php

regular file that you can get in github. So I don't understand the problem, any help?

Comment: have you enabled openssl extension..

Comment: sorry not understanding @ern :(

Comment: In your php.ini file is this line commented  `extension=php_openssl.dll ` .. Is there a  `; ` beggining of the line..